# Windows 10 installation gives "page fault in nonpaged area."

Tags: bsod, windows-10-upgrade

I own an original Windows 7 OS, and downloaded the update for Windows 10. After installation of files comes the installation of drivers and related files. The computer then reboots into Windows 10 bootscreen and I get a BSOD with the error message "page fault in nonpaged area." The computer proceeds to reboot a few times trying to recover the installation, then recovers the original OS. I have tried to fix this by modifying certain cache options in the system's properties. I have also ran an in depth hard drive scan. I know this error message could be due to a bad driver or a bad RAM, but I have failed to identify what is the error's source. Note that I am not getting this error with the Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 3):

> ...usually occurs after the installation of faulty
>   hardware or in the event of failure of installed hardware (usually
>   related to defective RAM, be it main memory, L2 RAM cache, or video
>   RAM).
>
> Another common cause is the installation of a faulty system service.
>
> Antivirus software can also trigger this error, as can a corrupted
>   NTFS volume.

Hopefully this can help guide you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559023(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In my case this was due to a memory overclock I had in place - removing the overclock allowed Windows to install.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sticks of ram, try pulling one out and doing the install again.

I have a 7 year old laptop with 2 2gig sticks in it.  I had tried everything I could find, and had run memtests for hours. Then, based on an answer in another forum I removed one stick (which got it to 2gig),and the install worked! I then reinstalled the ram and it worked fine!

Guess the windows 10 install routine is extra sensitive to multiple ram sticks.