# MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD - memtest86 showing no issues

Tags: windows-10, bsod, memory-management

I have just done a new I7 build and I am getting more BSODs than I'd like. I thought the first install might have had something go really wrong at some point, so I blew it away and started again. You can see I've had 3 BSODs since yesterday.

[image: BSOD]

I ran MEMTEST86, and it showed no issues after taking a day to run.

Can this BSOD be caused by dodgy drivers?

I've loaded the crash dumps in WINDBG, the most recent shows vmwp.exe as the running process, the previous one shows ngentask.exe.

What would be the next steps I take to diagnose the issue?

If anyone wants the results of `!analyze` from windbg, here goes:

```
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041793, The subtype of the bugcheck.
Arg2: fffff6809d59cff8
Arg3: 0000000000000200
Arg4: 00000000000001ff

Debugging Details:
------------------

Page 159ca not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details
Page 1080 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004" for details

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  F2

BIOS_DATE:  07/27/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  H170M-D3H-CF

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 41793

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff6809d59cff8

BUGCHECK_P3: 200

BUGCHECK_P4: 1ff

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41793

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: d50

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 23'00000000 (cache) 23'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  vmwp.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  FAMILY

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  02-21-2016 22:24:27.0933

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff802727eabab to fffff802727c6480

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`24efb538 fffff802`727eabab : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041793 fffff680`9d59cff8 00000000`00000200 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`24efb540 fffff802`726b6543 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`24efb809 00000000`00000000 00007ff5`ff61ffff : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x15dab
ffffd000`24efb740 fffff802`72ab6950 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`47d530a0 ffffe001`4223f680 ffffe001`422797c0 : nt!MiDeleteVad+0x3a3
ffffd000`24efb870 fffff802`72ab6777 : 00000000`00040000 ffffe001`4223f680 00000000`00000001 ffffe001`422797c0 : nt!MmCleanProcessAddressSpace+0x94
ffffd000`24efb8d0 fffff802`72a4e19b : ffffe001`422797c0 ffffc001`81fee060 ffffd000`24efb9c0 ffffe001`4223f680 : nt!PspRundownSingleProcess+0x117
ffffd000`24efb950 fffff802`72afeef6 : ffffe001`00000000 ffffe001`422797c0 ffffe001`422797c0 ffffe001`4223f680 : nt!PspExitThread+0x4f7
ffffd000`24efba90 fffff802`727d0ca3 : ffffe001`422797c0 ffffe001`4223f680 ffffd000`24efbb80 ffffd000`24efbb80 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0xde
ffffd000`24efbb00 00007fff`78d35604 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000034`dca7fb58 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007fff`78d35604


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  53b8912a4e8bc66404dcb8384b6660e10443ee81

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  205b2aa944e7090e1f96fc2bbfe11822ff56b666

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  cb5f414824c2521bcc505eaa03e92fa10922dad8

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+15dab
fffff802`727eabab cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  4f8b44cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+15dab

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56a849a9

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  15dab

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1a_41793_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

BUCKET_ID:  0x1a_41793_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x1a_41793_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_

TARGET_TIME:  2016-02-21T11:00:15.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-01-27 15:38:01

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160126-1819

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 877

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x1a_41793_nt!_??_::fnodobfm::_string_

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {2bb49b32-09fa-a96d-8b93-292cf7a50b3f}
```

Comment: run CPU-Z and check that the RAM timings match to the SPD values. Also change the Command Rate (CR) to 2 in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: have you checked the RAM timings?

Answer (score 0):

The ntoskrnl.exe errors may be caused by a number of issues, which make it hard to detect. They are most probably caused by an offending hardware / drivers. Since you have a memory error, please consider the following:

Run a memtest of at least a 6 pass (extended test), if not in double digits. It will take a long time. Please see this thread.

[How many passes are enough with Memtest?](https://superuser.com/questions/547822/how-many-passes-are-enough-with-memtest)

Please remove all RAM sticks and try with one stick or a pair (if required) at a time to troubleshoot. The bsod of fault in a non-paged area can also be a hardware problem. Please try adjusting the size of the paging file.

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/page-fault-in-non-paged-area-error/

[Windows 10 installation gives "page fault in nonpaged area."](https://superuser.com/questions/952417/windows-10-installation-gives-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Fix Page Fault in NonPaged Area

1. Adjust Paging File
2. Uninstall Third Party Antivirus
3. Check Disk
4. Due to Bad Driver

If there is still an error, then [read this](https://thedroidhax.com/page-fault-in-nonpaged-area/).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please [**edit your answer**](//superuser.com/posts/1337209/edit) so it contains that information. You might also like to take the [Tour] and read the [Answer] page, to better familiarise yourself with this site.

Comment: @robinCTS he's the owner and author of the article

Comment: @schroeder Nice to know. However, my first comment still applies. Plus it would probably be a good idea to add that as a disclaimer. (Otherwise, it could be considered to be spam.) cc johnabrahm

Comment: @robinCTS yes, I was informing you of the spam issue